# Wireless presenter with the shortest travel distance and lowest actuation force possible

Tags: wireless

I am looking for a wireless presenter (a.k.a. Powerpoint Clicker, Presentation Remote Control Pen) with the shortest [travel distance](https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/terms.php?t=Travel%20Distance) and lowest [actuation force](https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/terms.php?t=Actuation%20Force) possible. In other words, a wireless presenter  that requires as little force as possible to push the buttons. The wireless presenter I'm looking for does not need to be mechanical, though.

The wireless presenter just needs to have at least the basic features:

- one button for the previous slide
- one button for the next slide
- one button for laser pointer
- it should be compatible with Microsoft Windows
- it should be wireless.

I don't mind about the size, shape  and weight as long as I can hold it in one hand for one hour.  The price should be below 100 USD.

I have unsatisfyingly tried the following devices:

- [Inateck 2.4GHz Wireless Pointer Control Powerpoint Presentation Remote Control Clicker Presenter Pen, Cordless Powerpoint Slide Changer for Presentations - Remote Control Range: Up to 66ft, Black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LNP3VMA): the actuation force is too high (well above 50 cN)
- [Wireless Presenter, Doosl® Wireless Presenter, RF 2.4GHz Powerpoint Clicker Presentation Remote Control Pen.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YG8DWNE) : the actuation force is too high (well above 50 cN)

I am aware that there exist presentation tools, such as Niftio, have features that can allow to use a phone as a wireless presenter, but I would prefer not to have to rely on a phone.

Comment: Hmm.......the only reason I know of newtonian measurements is from rocketry, due to thrust being measured in newton-seconds....so....50 centinewtons = .5 newtons = 0.1124044712215Lbs of force (yay math?).....I'll look around for any place that may possibly post reviews including button-press force....after I get some sleep tho, 1:15am lol.

Comment: Not many listings of actuation pressure for some reason, still looking though...